# Why SetKwData defined macro for algorithm2e doesn't work in caption?

Tags: macros, captions, algorithm2e

I defined a macro with `\SetKwData` command from `algorithm2e` but it doesn't seem to be working in the caption.

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwData{Result}{result}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{ \(x\) and \(y\)  }
  \KwOut{ \Result }
  \( \Result \leftarrow x + y \) \;
  \Return{ \Result  }
  \caption{ This is a caption with \Result. }
\end{algorithm}
In here I talk about the \Result of \(x + y \).

\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.72   \caption{ This is a caption with \Result. }
```

Comment: A tip: if you select the code snippet and click on the `{}` button (or hit Control-K), the formatting will be better; the `<pre>...</pre>` method is to be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `\protect` the `\result` or use the optional short caption.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwData{Result}{result}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{ \(x\) and \(y\)  }
  \KwOut{ \Result }
  \( \Result \leftarrow x + y \) \;
  \Return{ \Result  }
  \caption{ This is a caption with \protect\Result. }
\end{algorithm}
In here I talk about the \Result of \(x + y \).

\end{document}
```

---

## Side note

Apart from the missing `\protect`, your input has several wrong spaces. Recall that spaces are ignored in math mode, but not in all cases when TeX is typesetting text. So you should be more careful: `\Return{ \Result }` is not the same as `\Return{\Result}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwData{Result}{result}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{\(x\) and \(y\)}
  \KwOut{\Result}
  \( \Result \leftarrow x + y \) \;
  \Return{\Result}
  \caption{This is a caption with \protect\Result.}
\end{algorithm}
In here I talk about the \Result of \(x + y \).

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was answering the same, but adding also something about the excess spaces in the input.

Comment: No, you came first. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the side note. I think I got some errors in the past I solved with some additional spacing and just started spreading spaces all around. I'll try to read something about this.

Comment: @FernandoCésar: Sidenotes credit should go to the master. :)

Comment: Thanks for the side note @egreg. I think I got some errors in the past I solved with some additional spacing and just started spreading spaces all around. I'll try to read something about this.

Comment: @egreg, I was just trying out and `\Return{ \Result } !\;`and `\Return{\Result} !\;` seem to output exactly the same. What am I missing here? (Maybe I should ask another question?)

Comment: @FernandoCésar In my experiment, `\Return{ \Result}` and `\Return{\Result}` give different output. See the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ItZ4.png)

Comment: @egreg, Maybe you are using a different configuration. But from what I've been reading, "In math mode, the spaces in your source file are completely ignored by LaTeX with just two exceptions". (From [here](http://crab.rutgers.edu/~karel/latex/class5/class5.html))

Comment: @FernandoCésar But `\Return{\Result}`, in your code is *not* in math mode.

Comment: @egreg, only now did I get your point! You're right (of course). Maybe this is a feature of algorithm2e? My algorithms never seem to have extra spaces.

Comment: @FernandoCésar `\(...\)` is fragile. Use `$...$` instead or use optional argument of caption like `\caption[This is a caption]{This is a caption with \protect\Result.}`